# Xamarin Android and custom control: Unable to activate instance

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I'm creating my custom control for a tag edit. I'm using `Visual Studio 2019` and `Xamarin Forms`. It is working for `UWP` and `iOS` but in `Android` I have an error with the native renderer.

[image: Error]

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.EntryRenderer from native handle 0x7feca76624 (key_handle 0x95e8e41).

The output is:

> 04-24 10:10:11.382 W/InputMethodManager(17644): startInputReason = 4
>   04-24 10:10:11.415 I/HwSecImmHelper(17644):
>   mSecurityInputMethodService is null 04-24 10:10:11.446
>   W/ResourceType(17644): No package identifier when getting name for
>   resource number 0x00000000 04-24 10:10:11.448 W/View    (17644):
>   dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring 04-24
>   10:10:11.453 I/AssistStructure(17644): Flattened final assist data:
>   2444 bytes, containing 1 windows, 10 views 04-24 10:10:12.379
>   I/zygote64(17644): Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB,
>   data=54KB 04-24 10:10:12.379 I/zygote64(17644): After code cache
>   collection, code=61KB, data=54KB 04-24 10:10:12.379 I/zygote64(17644):
>   Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB 04-24 10:10:14.160
>   W/zygote64(17644): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0
>   native methods for md58432a647068b097f9637064b8985a5e0.FrameRenderer
>   04-24 10:10:14.220 W/InputMethodManager(17644): startInputReason = 4
>   04-24 10:10:14.259 W/InputMethodManager(17644): startInputReason = 4
>   04-24 10:10:14.260 I/zygote64(17644): Compiler allocated 5MB to
>   compile void android.view.View.(android.content.Context,
>   android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) 04-24 10:10:14.263
>   W/InputMethodManager(17644): startInputReason = 3 04-24 10:10:14.284
>   I/HwSecImmHelper(17644): mSecurityInputMethodService is null 04-24
>   10:10:14.379 I/zygote64(17644): Do full code cache collection,
>   code=108KB, data=98KB 04-24 10:10:14.380 I/zygote64(17644): After code
>   cache collection, code=101KB, data=74KB 04-24 10:10:14.568 D/Mono
>   (17644): Loading reference 6 of Mono.Android.dll asmctx DEFAULT,
>   looking for System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e 04-24 10:10:14.570
>   D/Mono    (17644): Image addref
>   System.Runtime.Serialization[0x7e53d21780] (asmctx DEFAULT) ->
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0x7e51894800]: 2mono_pe_file_map:
>   Error opening file System.Runtime.Serialization.dll (3): No such file
>   or directory
>
> 04-24 10:10:14.570 D/Mono    (17644): Prepared to set up assembly
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization' (System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)
>   04-24 10:10:14.570 D/Mono    (17644): Assembly
>   System.Runtime.Serialization[0x7e53d21780] added to domain RootDomain,
>   ref_count=1 04-24 10:10:14.572 D/Mono    (17644): AOT: image
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed:
>   library "System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found 04-24
>   10:10:14.572 D/Mono    (17644): AOT: image
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d16-0/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-arm64-v8a-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm64/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d16-0/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-arm64-v8a-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm64/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found 04-24 10:10:14.572 D/Mono    (17644): Config attempting to
>   parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'. 04-24 10:10:14.572
>   D/Mono    (17644): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d16-0/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-arm64-v8a-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
>   04-24 10:10:14.572 D/Mono    (17644): Assembly Ref addref
>   Mono.Android[0x7e56659a80] ->
>   System.Runtime.Serialization[0x7e53d21780]: 2 04-24 10:10:14.573
>   D/Mono    (17644): Loading reference 0 of
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
>   04-24 10:10:14.573 D/Mono    (17644): Assembly Ref addref
>   System.Runtime.Serialization[0x7e53d21780] -> mscorlib[0x7e77dc3c80]:
>   40 Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
>   Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.EntryRenderer from native handle
>   0x7feca76624 (key_handle 0x95e8e41).

The component adds a runtime a new `Entry` in a `Layout<View>`.
This is what I expect also in Android.

[image: Result of TagEdit]

The full source code of my component is on [Github](https://github.com/erossini/TagEntry). The important part is here:

```
public class TagEntryView : Layout<View>, IDisposable
{
    TagEntry TagEntry;

    public TagEntryView()
    {
        PropertyChanged += TagEntryViewPropertyChanged;
        PropertyChanging += TagEntryViewPropertyChanging;

        TagEntry = new TagEntry();
        TagEntry.TextChanged += TagEntryTextChanged;
        Children.Add(TagEntry);
    }

    void TagEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TagSeparators != null)
        {
            if (TagSeparators.Any(e.NewTextValue.Contains))
            {
                string tag = e.NewTextValue;
                foreach (var item in TagSeparators)
                {
                    tag = tag.Replace(item, string.Empty);
                }

                if (TagValidatorFactory != null)
                {
                    var tagBindingContext = TagValidatorFactory(tag);
                    var tagEntry = sender as Entry;

                    if (tagBindingContext != null)
                    {
                        TagItems.Add(tagBindingContext);
                        tagEntry.Text = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tagEntry.Text = tag;
                    }

                    tagEntry.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more details, I created two videos where I show in parallel what it is happing on Visual Studio and Android device.

Here what I'm doing on the [Android device](https://youtu.be/ap_V7bsJLoM). Here debug in [Visual Studio](https://youtu.be/HeQTNt1U6hE).

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Jaymin I updated my post and also you can find the component on Github.

Comment: I previously updated XF to solve a similar problem "Unable to activate instance of type ..."，not sure if it works for you

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I'm using the latest version of XF. I still have the same issue